# How to show the footer of active reports just in last page of the report?

Tags: footer, activereports

I'm showing a total of records in the footer of the page but is showing it for each page is any option for show it just in the last one?

Comment: Just in case that be useful for one my problem was that I was trying to use a page footer for add a summarize value on last page instead to use a reportFooter. So I just added a ReportFooter with my value and that was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way i.e use ReportFooter instead of PageFooter. If you wish to print the total at the bottom of the last page, you can set ReportFooter's PrintAtBottom property to true.